# Does the set $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{0/n,1/n,...,n/n\}$ contain irrational members? Does it equal the interval [0,1]?

Tags: limits, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Please pardon my lack of mathematical sophistication, but I wonder whether such a set of rational elements would converge upon a closed interval as the divisor, and therefore the number of elements in the set, approaches infinity, and the distance between the elements becomes smaller and smaller.

Comment: What is your definition of the limit of a  sequence of sets?

Comment: What is meant by the limit of a set? Do you mean $\cap_n A_n$ or $\cup_n A_n$? (where $A_n$ is your set). The standard limit is defined for sequences and functions.

Comment: @NesDLover: There are several definitions of limits of sequences of sets. If $A_n$ was a nested sequence of sets then the limit can be defined as union or intersection. There are also limits in the sense of Hausdorff or Gromov-Hausdorff (if the sets are not compact).

Comment: I mean the union of the sets with successive values of n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which limit you consider (there are several different definitions). But if you consider simply the set of limits of all converging sequences of rational numbers then the limit is the unit closed interval.You get the same result if you consider the Hausdorff limit.

Comment: Thank you, @JCAA.  I apologize for my stumbling, mathematically inept formulation of the question.  The reason I asked the question is because I am trying to determine whether it is possible to find a "continuized" (i.e., real-domain) equivalent of an integer-domain function, with more stringent criteria than simply that every ordered pair in the latter must be included in the former.  In my process of narrowing down the eligible functions, I proceed with domains that are successively larger subsets of the rational numbers.  I wondered whether irrationals would eventually be subsumed.

Comment: @JustAsking, I guess that you have fallen into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It may be a good idea to ask the original question (preferably as a separate post, since modifying the question with answers will likely render those answers less related).

Answer (score 0):

Let's carefully see what you are asking for:
Let $$S_1=\{0,1\},\quad S_2=\left\{0,\dfrac12, 1\right\},\quad S_3=\left\{0, \dfrac13, \dfrac23, 1\right\},\quad\cdots,$$ than you want to know if this sequence of sets converge to some other set. Before this we need to have a meaning (precise definition) for convergence of a sequence of finite sets inside some bigger space containing it. We can resolve this situation by introducing a appropriate (in general) topology, or a (complete) metric on the latter set. There are multiple ways to do this and I do not see any canonical way to do this.

Let me give you a toy example of the procedure I explain above. Consider the set $S$ of all subsets of $[0, 1]$ with discrete metric, that is,
$$d(S^1, S^2)=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $S^1=S^2$} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Here all Cauchy sequences sequences are eventually constant and hence, in this model, your sequence $\{S_1, S_2, S_3, \cdots\}$ does not converges.

Comment: It should be noted that your definition of the limit of a sequence of sets is probably the most restrictive possible in terms of what is considered convergent.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite union isn't a limit.  It's an infinite union and it doesn't contain anything not in any of the sets.

So no, there union contains no irrational number.

But for any rational $r\in [0,1]$ we have $r = \frac ab, a,b \in \mathbb N$ and $a < b$ so $r=\frac ab \in \{0,\frac 1b, \frac 2b, ...., \frac bb\}$.

So the infinite union is $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q = $ all the rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$.

There's no such thing as sequence of sets converging to a set as a limit.

Comment: The last sentence in this answer is false. There are several non-equivalent definitions of converging sequences of sets. That includes unions of increasing sequences and intersections of decreasing sequences of sets. One can also take the closure of the union, the Hausdorff limit and the Gromov-Hausdorff limit. Considering sets as functions (the indicator functions) one can use several limits from the functional analysis and operator theory.